# Javascript regex difficult replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new with regex, could you help me to solve this?

I want to replace

> Some text and XXblaaaaa# and text again XXbl!abla# or XXblalala# or XXbabla#

with

> Some text and OOTEXT** and text again OOTEXT** or OOTEXT**

[I made a jsfiddle to test t.](http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/1/)

My regex for test is:  `/((XX).+?(?=(#)))/g;`, i.e., find `XX` untill `#`.

But how can I set the following condition: untill `#` if string between `XX` and `#` does not contain `!`?

Comment: Why does `XXbl!abla# or` disappear from your string though?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. For each `!` you want to ignore the next `#`, instead of skipping the entire `XX..!..#` thing.

Comment: Sorry, a open new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382328/regex-to-detect-urls-with-character-at-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the overload of `.replace(regex,function)`:

```
var txt = 'Some text and XXblaaaaa# and text again XXbl!abla# or XXblalala# or XXbabla#';
var result = .replace(/(XX.*?#)/g,function(m,a){
  // only replace values that do not contain a '!'
  return a.indexOf('!') == -1 ? 'OOTEXT**' : a;
});
// "Some text and OOTEXT** and text again XXbl!abla# or OOTEXT** or OOTEXT**"
```

I'm not sure if your example was really that simple, so the above is a method with a lot of flexibility. You could also use `[^!]*?` in place of the `.*?`, but anything more complex then a single character will need to be more elaborate.

Comment: It does have lookaheads.

Comment: @m.buettner: indeed, I think was was thinking of look-behinds. There's one is has and one it doesn't, but never quite remember. ;-)

Comment: Yes, excactly. It doesn't have lookbehinds, but it does have lookaheads.

Answer (score 1):

```
/XX[^!]*?#/g
```

This will replace everything from XX to #, as long as it doesn't include an !

Used like this:

```
"Some text and XXblaaaaa# and text again XXbl!abla# or XXblalala# or XXbabla#".replace(/XX[^!]*?#/g, "OOTEXT");
```

EDIT:

A more efficient version would be like this:

```
    /XX[^!#]*#/g
```

And if you don't want to allow whitespace, then add `\s` in the character class

```
/XX[^!#\s]*#/g
```

Comment: Why not put the `#` inside the character class, too, to get rid of the ungreediness?

Comment: I think this way is easier to understand because it looks more like the OP's description. "From XX to # without including `!`"

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't advocate best practices ;).

Comment: @m.buettner: Sometimes readability over a [nominal] optimization is better. ;-)

Comment: I agree. But readability is also a best practice. I'll add it for completeness.

Comment: @BradChristie I'm not questioning that. But I think this page is about being a knowledge base, so it's certainly worth mentioning all the trade-offs of a particular solution.

Comment: /XX[^!]*?#/g this will replace XX.+# and skip if !

Comment: ..and skip if '!' but need skip # if ! contains

Comment: 'XXbl!abla# or XXblalala#' replaced to 'OOTEXT**' coz contained '!' inside

Comment: What? All three examples here turn `'XXbl!abla# or XXblalala#'` into `"XXbl!abla# or OOTEXT"`

Comment: @ColBeseder yeah, I think the OP wants to turn the whole thing into `OOTEXT` only ... that is, `XX...!...#` should not be ignored, but each `!` should cause the engine to skip the next `#`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
result = input.replace(/XX[^!#]*(?:![^#]*#[^!#]*)*#/g, "OOTEXT**");
```

How does it work? We match `XX`, then we consume as many non-`!`, non-`#` characters as possible. The next group `(?:![^#]#[^!#]*)` matches a `!`, then consumes everything until the next `#` and continues with non-`#`, non-`!` as before. This part is repeated as many times as necessary, until we find a `#` that was not preceded by `!`.