# Regex to detect urls with '?' character at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I found many solutions, but none was useful for me.

Let's say, as an example, I want to find URLs that start with `www.` and end with a space or  `?`.  In this case, I really mean it ends in a `?`, not that it's necessarily a CGI-related URL.

I'm trying to use the regex

```
var r = /(^|[\s\?])(www\..+?(?=([\s]|\?|($))))/g;
```

My sample use: http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/2/

How can I use `\?` in a regex to prevent the end of the URL containing `/` before `?`?

http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/11/

I can't solve last prob with DOT at the end of url.
Can any body help?

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. Are you wanting to detect a domain name that has a `?` in it somewhere, as long as it's not `/?` ?

Comment: A sample of what _should_ and what _shouldn't_ return true would be helpful here.

Comment: yes, string 'www.domain.com?www.domeain.net' contain 2 urls, yes? next string 'www.domain.com/cgi/script.pl?www.domeain.net' contain one url with cgi parameters

Comment: so, first string replaced as <a>www.domain.com</a>?<a>www.domeain.net</a>

Comment: second '<a>www.domain.com/cgi/script.pl?www.domeain.net</a>'

Comment: From the "regex" tag wiki (hover over the tag and click "info"): "*[Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/) [is a] Useful and searchable library for regular expressions. It is better to search inside it first before asking related questions to this tag.*" URI/URL Expressions: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2

Comment: I spend two days, read many docs and pages, google, stackoverflow, regular-expressions.info and more sites in search of the Solution. Sorry, wiki was very far from my hands and eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your fiddle:

```
var r = /(^|\??)(www\.[^\?]+)/g;
```

I updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/3/

*Update:*

I see what you are trying to do now.  Unfortunately, both your strings are essentially the same, apart from the `/`, so unless you want your regex to make the assumption that a `?` anywhere after a slash denotes a CGI call, then there isn't much you can do.  But you could try this:

```
var r = /(^|\??)(www\.[^\?]+\/[^\/]+\?[^\?]+|www\.[^\?]+)/g;
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/5/

*Update 2:* After determining the requirements, this is the final RegExp I added to fiddle 10:

```
var r = /(^|[\?\s])(www\.[^\? ]+\/[^\/ ]*\?[^\? ]+|www\.[^\? ]+)/g;
```

Comment: i uncomment string where ? as cgi

Comment: They use TLD list to detect domain end and next they search space or other not logic char to find real end of url

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: ' and text with www.domain.net again' separate. But its as long url with cgi

Comment: and www.domain.net at the end tagged (A) too

Comment: Ooohh!!! Very good!! One thing still alittle not so good. Could you see http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/9/    I add case where cgi query without  script name, its offen meets in internet.

Comment: Please see first mutch

Comment: Craig, how can i send you private msg?

Comment: Hi Craig, could you help with prob with DOT at the end of url?  http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/11/